# How to have checkboxes checked by default using useFormik?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, formik, ref

I have these components and I have 12 checkboxes in child component. I want to have them checked by default when the component loads. I can't do that. I can't use `checked='true'` as an attribute for my input because formik is controlling my input and it doesn't work well. Or I set checked attribute with some pre-defined values in checked array, but again it worked badly. I thought I probably can use useRef here to trigger `onChange` event of input to simulate changing checkboxes by checking them. something like this:

```
const ref = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
ref.current.change();
}, [])
```

and setting ref to the input. But this didn't work. How can I fix this problem with ref or something else?

```
    import {useFormik} from "formik";
    import CheckboxesComponent from "./CheckboxesComponent";
    
    const AddUserForm = ({handleShowForm, showForm, formTitle}) => {
        const cities = options.slice(1)
        const [textAreaString, setTextArea] = useState('')
    
        const formik = useFormik({
            initialValues: {
                tel: '', name: '', password: '', username: '', province: '', level: '', availableCities: '', city: '',
                checked: []
            },
            onSubmit: values => {
                console.log(formik.values)
            }
        })
    
        return(
            <form className='add-user-form' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                <div className='form-flex'>
                   {/*other parts of form*/}
                </div>
                <CheckboxesComponent handleChange={formik.handleChange} />
            </form>
        )
    }
    export default AddUserForm
```

CheckBoxesComponent:

```
const fields = [
    {name: 'delNomad', label: 'حذف عشایر'},
    {name: 'editNomad', label: 'ویرایش عشایر'},
    {name: 'addNomad', label: 'افزودن عشایر'},
    {name: 'delDriver', label: 'حذف راننده'},
    {name: 'editDriver', label: 'ویرایش راننده'},
    {name: 'addDriver', label: 'افزودن راننده'},
    {name: 'rejectReq', label: 'رد درخواست ها'},
    {name: 'manualDeliver', label: 'تایید تحویل دستی'},
    {name: 'addWaterReq', label: 'افزودن درخواست آب'},
    {name: 'getExcel', label: 'دریافت فایل اکسل'},
    {name: 'seeingReport', label: 'مشاهده گزارش گیری'},
    {name: 'delReq', label: 'حذف درخواست ها'},
];

const CheckboxesComponent = ({handleChange}) => {

    return(
        <div className='checkboxes-part'>
            {fields.map((item, index) => {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <label>{item.label}</label>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='checked' value={item.name} onChange={handleChange} />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CheckboxesComponent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by setting a defaultChecked to checkboxes:

```
import {useFormik} from "formik";
import CheckboxesComponent from "./CheckboxesComponent";

const AddUserForm = ({handleShowForm, showForm, formTitle}) => {
    const cities = options.slice(1)
    const [textAreaString, setTextArea] = useState('')

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            tel: '', name: '', password: '', username: '', province: '', level: '', availableCities: '', city: '',
            checked: ['delNomad','editNomad','addNomad','delDriver','editDriver','addDriver','rejectReq','manualDeliver',
            'addWaterReq','getExcel','seeingReport','delReq']
        },
        onSubmit: values => {
            console.log(formik.values)
        }
    })

    return(
        <form className='add-user-form' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <div className='form-flex'>
               {/*other parts of form*/}
            </div>
            <CheckboxesComponent handleChange={formik.handleChange} />
        </form>
    )
}
export default AddUserForm


const fields = [
    {name: 'delNomad', label: 'حذف عشایر'},
    {name: 'editNomad', label: 'ویرایش عشایر'},
    {name: 'addNomad', label: 'افزودن عشایر'},
    {name: 'delDriver', label: 'حذف راننده'},
    {name: 'editDriver', label: 'ویرایش راننده'},
    {name: 'addDriver', label: 'افزودن راننده'},
    {name: 'rejectReq', label: 'رد درخواست ها'},
    {name: 'manualDeliver', label: 'تایید تحویل دستی'},
    {name: 'addWaterReq', label: 'افزودن درخواست آب'},
    {name: 'getExcel', label: 'دریافت فایل اکسل'},
    {name: 'seeingReport', label: 'مشاهده گزارش گیری'},
    {name: 'delReq', label: 'حذف درخواست ها'},
];

const CheckboxesComponent = ({handleChange}) => {

    return(
        <div className='checkboxes-part'>
            {fields.map((item, index) => {
                return(
                    <div key={index}>
                        <label>{item.label}</label>
                        <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked={true} name='checked' value={item.name} onChange={handleChange} />
                    </div>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CheckboxesComponent
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add checked attribute in input and also check with value of formic something like below.

```
const fields = [
    { name: 'delNomad', label: 'حذف عشایر' },
    { name: 'editNomad', label: 'ویرایش عشایر' },
    { name: 'addNomad', label: 'افزودن عشایر' },
    { name: 'delDriver', label: 'حذف راننده' },
    { name: 'editDriver', label: 'ویرایش راننده' },
    { name: 'addDriver', label: 'افزودن راننده' },
    { name: 'rejectReq', label: 'رد درخواست ها' },
    { name: 'manualDeliver', label: 'تایید تحویل دستی' },
    { name: 'addWaterReq', label: 'افزودن درخواست آب' },
    { name: 'getExcel', label: 'دریافت فایل اکسل' },
    { name: 'seeingReport', label: 'مشاهده گزارش گیری' },
    { name: 'delReq', label: 'حذف درخواست ها' },
];

const CheckboxesComponent = ({ checklist, handleChange }) => {

    return (
        <div className='checkboxes-part'>
            {
                fields.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={index}>
                            <label>{item.label}</label>
                            <input type='checkbox' name='checked' value={item.name} checked={checklist.some((FieldItem) => item.name === FieldItem)} onChange={handleChange} />
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default CheckboxesComponent;
```

add user form should be like this

```
import {useFormik} from "formik";
import CheckboxesComponent from "./CheckboxesComponent";

const AddUserForm = ({handleShowForm, showForm, formTitle}) => {
    const cities = options.slice(1)
    const [textAreaString, setTextArea] = useState('')

    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues: {
            tel: '', name: '', password: '', username: '', province: '', level: '', availableCities: '', city: '',
            checked: ['delNomad','editNomad','addNomad','delDriver','editDriver','addDriver','rejectReq','manualDeliver','addWaterReq','getExcel','seeingReport','delReq']
        },
        onSubmit: values => {
            console.log(formik.values)
        }
    })

    return(
        <form className='add-user-form' onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
            <div className='form-flex'>
                {/*other parts of form*/}
            </div>
            <CheckboxesComponent checklist={formik.values.checked} handleChange={formik.handleChange} />
        </form>
    )
}
export default AddUserForm;
```

Comment: But it doesn't work. It didn't show any checkbox in output. In your code you used one map for component and another one inside that for checkboxes!

Comment: I just update this code with 2 changes. 1. add all value checked in formik initialValues. 2. change checked condition in your CheckboxesComponent. now check this with your code, it should work for you.

Comment: I fixed it with `defaultChecked`. I'll answer my question.

Comment: I don't know if this works or not, thanks anyway:)

Comment: defaultChecked will only show as checked, but value of checked in formik will still remain blank array. whenever user will click on checkbox it will diselect after 2 click.

Comment: But I put all values in the array in advance, so it's not empty in the beginning. It works now